# Firefox doesn't support jQuery append method it will always go to the top in <select> Chrome IE works well

Tags: jquery, firefox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
 function generateScrolldown() {
  var html = "";
  html = html + ('<option>'
                 + 'dddddd'
                 + "</option>");
  $("#dynamicDLmultiAvailableList").append(html);
 }
</script>


<h1>The template Tag</h1>

<div>
 <select class="form-control"
  id="dynamicDLmultiAvailableList" multiple size="12" onscroll="generateScrolldown()">
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
  <option>sdsdsdsdsd</option>
 </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On firefox this small piece of code doesn't have proper layout I tried to scroll down and append() method will add new element to  but scroll button doesn't go down and always shows at the top.

Also tried on IE and Chrome no this issue

Anyone know how to append new element in  and works well in firefox thanks.

Comment: You question is slightly misleading.  The append works, and is doing what it is supposed to.  Your issue appears that you expect it to scroll, or something, and it is not.

Comment: Yes append works fine but if you use firefox the drop-down menu doesn't go down so you can not see new append elements. But on IE and Chrome I didn't see this issue.

Comment: Right, but that's not an issue with append.  Append has nothing to do with scrolling.  If the browser does, or does not scroll, is a side effect.

Comment: Yes that's browser issue and my customers they only use firefox and I am now trying to find some way to solve this problem.